# Hey! How can i solve my code which apparently isnt properly taking .key property from KeyboardEvent from browser?

Tags: javascript, canvas, input, keyboard-events

KeyboardEvent has its "predefined" value = .key depending of what key you press on keyboard but even when mine console says that i clicked certain key i cannot "define" key value....

i tried googling solutions & defining key value on its own but nothing worked
im a bit clueless at this point

```
  let canvas= document.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.width=800;canvas.height=600;const ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
//bg
ctx.fillStyle='black';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
//player
ctx.fillStyle='white';
let player_x=30;
let player_y=60;
ctx.fillRect(player_x,player_y,40,400);
//controls
function Input(event){ 
    let ifPressed=event.key;
    console.log(ifPressed);
          if(ifPressed==="w"){
             player_y-=5;
    } else if(ifPressed==="s"){
          player_y+=5;
   }

  }

document.addEventListener('keydown',Input);
Input();
```

I've tried it this way but console always says ".key" is not defined while it should get key property from KeyboardEvent in browser

Comment: Always show the exact error message as text in your questions. But my guess is that this is a well-defined part of the KeyboardEvent API. If a key cannot be found the return value is some kind of "unidentified" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `Input();` at last line and create `<canvas></canvas>` element in your body html. I add this two fixes to your code and it works (run snippet, scroll down, click on canvas and start type):

```js
let canvas= document.querySelector('canvas');
    canvas.width=800;canvas.height=600;const ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
//bg
ctx.fillStyle='black';
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
//player
ctx.fillStyle='white';
let player_x=30;
let player_y=60;
ctx.fillRect(player_x,player_y,40,400);
//controls
function Input(event){ 
    let ifPressed=event.key;
    console.log(ifPressed);
          if(ifPressed==="w"){
             player_y-=5;
    } else if(ifPressed==="s"){
          player_y+=5;
   }

  }


document.addEventListener('keydown',Input);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you,fixed it eventually :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to redraw your player with every keydown. I've putted all the drawing in a function `draw()`

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = 800;
canvas.height = 600;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let player_x = 30;
let player_y = 60;
draw();
function Input(event) {
  let ifPressed = event.key;
  console.log(ifPressed);
  if (ifPressed === "w") {
    player_y -= 5;
    draw();
  } else if (ifPressed === "s") {
    player_y += 5;
    draw();
  }
  
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", Input);

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(player_x, player_y, 40, 400);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```